# Só consigo acessar o primeiro fragment com abas

Tags: android, android-fragment

Depois de algum tempo sem atualizar meus apps tenho que alterá-los para adaptar ao Admob 7.0.0.

Em dois deles uso `fragments` em abas (um com duas abas e outro com três) e ele sempre se posiciona no primeiro deles e sempre funcionou.

Agora, ao executar os *apps* eles não fazem nada ao clicar no título das outras abas, ou seja, eu fico preso à primeira aba.

Um dos parâmetros a serem analisados é que é a primeira vez que compilo estes apps no Android 3.0.

O que acham que pode ser?

O *app* que não tem `fragment` nem aba funciona normalmente.

O mais estranho é que quando eu saio do aplicativo a aba onde cliquei aparece rapidamente e some. Muito estranho

Quando eu clico na aba que não é mostrada dá o seguinte erro lo `logcat`, sem interromper o *app*:

```
01-19 16:35:46.795 2357-2734/? E/DatabaseUtils: Writing exception to parcel
java.lang.SecurityException: Permission Denial: get/set setting for user asks to run as user -2 but is calling from user 0; this requires android.permission.INTERACT_ACROSS_USERS_FULL
at com.android.server.am.ActivityManagerService.handleIncomingUser(ActivityManagerService.java:13140)
at android.app.ActivityManager.handleIncomingUser(ActivityManager.java:2038)
at com.android.providers.settings.SettingsProvider.callFromPackage(SettingsProvider.java:607)
at android.content.ContentProvider$Transport.call(ContentProvider.java:279)
at android.content.ContentProviderNative.onTransact(ContentProviderNative.java:273)
at android.os.Binder.execTransact(Binder.java:388)
at dalvik.system.NativeStart.run(Native Method)
```

Comment: Esse logcat está dizendo para pedir a permissão `android.permission.INTERACT_ACROSS_USERS_FULL`.

Comment: Eu coloquei mas não resolveu. Acabei por colocar o minSdkVersion 19 para evitar este problema.